# How to execute a custom hook from another hook in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I'm developping a module for prestashop 1.7.3 which handle price reductions depending on the cart content. I'm using two hooks (1. **displayFidelityProgramCartTop** and 2. **actionCartSave**) and perform actions inside the `hookActionCartSave($params)` method : depending on the result, I need to refresh the data returned by the first hook.

I use the `Hook::exec('displayFidelityProgramCartTop', array())` at the end of the `hookActionCartSave($params)` method but it seems that the hook isn't executed. The hook is correctly called once, at the initialization.  How can I manage to refresh the data returned by the hook (= re-executing the hook to update the template) ?

My code :

**cart.tpl**

```
..
{hook h='displayFidelityProgramCartTop' mod='programmeproplus'}
..
```

**programmeproplus.php** (main module file)

```
public function install(){ 
   ..
   $this->registerHook('displayFidelityProgramCartTop') && 
   $this->registerHook('actionCartSave')
   ..
}

public function hookActionCartSave() {
   // Perform some actions .. 
   Hook::exec('displayFidelityProgramCartTop', array());
}


public function hookDisplayFidelityProgramCartTop(){ 
   // Perform some actions .. 
   return "<p>List of promotions : ".$promotions."</p>";
}
```